# usage of "before" as Conjunction

Tags: subordinate-clauses

Can I '**re-write**' the sentence,

"If I finish my homework, I can go out at the weekend."

as,

"I can't go out at the weekend **before I** finish my homework."

Comment: "on the weekend", not "at the weekend".

Answer (score 1):

I think you are close, but there are small grammatical issues in both sentences. I would suggest changing the sentences to the following:

> If I finish my homework, I can go out ***this weekend***.
>
> I can't go out this weekend ***until*** I finish my homework.

***Until*** should be used instead of ***before***, which sounds awkward.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning is similar, but there is a subtle difference.

The sentence:

> "If I finish my homework, I can go out this weekend"

Says something about what is true if the condition is true.  If I finish my homework, then the rest of this sentence is true.  Often times the opposite is implied and you will often hear people draw this conclusion, but it is not entirely correct.  In other words, the above sentence is *not* the opposite of the following:

> "If I don't finish my homework, I cannot go out this weekend."

This phrase is heavily implied, but not strictly true, as an if statement such as this only talks about what will be true if the condition is true.  Take the following example:  "If it rains, I will bring my umbrella".  This says nothing about whether or not I will bring my umbrella if it *doesn't* rain, though most people tend to make that assumption just the same.

Your second sentence isn't just implying this meaning.  It is stating it outright.

Also, I agree with @Ringo on the latter point.  It is better to use "until" rather than "before".

Comment: To add to your point, as stated [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_(logic)), “the inverse of a conditional cannot be inferred from the conditional.” “If P then Q” does not imply “If not P then not Q.”

Comment: @Mixolydian Misinterpretation of this rule is often what makes many jokes possible.  :)